# prevent uploading duplicate files with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building one file upload where i need to prevent upload duplicate files.
I tried some ways but its not happening.
Here is my code

```js
var fileArray = [];
var fileCount = 0;
function readUrl(input) {
  fileCount = 0;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
    var fsize = input.files[i].size,
      ftype = input.files[i].type,
      fname = input.files[i].name,
      fNameArray = [];
    (fFormat = fname.split(".").pop()),
      (fextension = fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
    validExtensions = [
      "jpg",
      "pdf",
      "jpeg",
      "tiff",
      "gif",
      "png",
      "PNG",
      "doc",
      "docx"
    ];
    fNameArray.push(fname);
    fNameArray.join(",");
    if ($.inArray(fextension, validExtensions) == -1) {
      $.alert({
        icon: "fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-5x",
        title: "",
        theme: "my-theme",
        content: "This type of files are not allowed!"
      });

      $(input).val("");
      return false;
    } else if (fsize > 10000000) {
      /*1048576-1MB(You can change the size as you want)*/
      $.alert({
        icon: "fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-5x",
        title: "",
        theme: "my-theme",
        content: "File size too large! Please upload less than 10MB"
      });

      $(input).val("");
      return false;
    } else {
      fileArray.push([fname, fFormat]);
      fileArray.join(",");
      let file = input.files[i];
      var form = new FormData();
      form.append("Token", localStorage.tokenId);
      form.append("UserId", $("#loginDetails").text());
      form.append("Roles", $("#roleType").val());
      form.append("CanEmailID", $("#eAddress").text());
      form.append("file", file);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + "api/DocUpload/UploadDocument",
        //dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
          $(".spinner-container").show();
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        data: form,
        success: function(response) {
          fileCount++;
          let ul = document.getElementById("appendedList");

          ul.innerHTML +=
            '<li><span class="styleList w-50 d-inline-block mr-3">' +
            file.name +
            "</span>" +
            "<span class='mx-2 font-italic' style='font-size:0.8em'>File " +
            fileCount +
            " of " +
            i +
            " </span><span class='delNode' onclick='deleteNode(this)'>X</span></li>";
          $(input)
            .prev()
            .text("Drag and drop another file or page \u000A or \u000A Browse");

          /*  document.body.querySelector(
              "a[data-docid=" + ref + "]"
            ).parentNode.previousSibling.innerHTML = fileSize / 1000 + " KB"; */
        },

        complete: function() {
          $(".spinner-container").hide();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
          if (jqXHR.status && jqXHR.status == 400) {
            window.location.assign(accessUrl + "/axa/502.html");
          } else {
            window.location.assign(accessUrl + "/axa/502.html");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

i have create one array  fNameArray where i'm saving the uploaded file names.But i'm not able to identify whether particular file is already added to it.
Is this the correct way or i'm using wrong approach to  achieve this.
Or any alternative would be the great. But i want to this in inside of `readUrl` function only.